# pg: exec_params not replacing parameters?

Tags: ruby, pg

First time using `pg` gem to access postgres database. I've connected successfully and can run queries using `#exec`, but now building a simple query with `#exec_params` does not seem to be replacing parameters. I.e:

```
get '/databases/:db/tables/:table' do |db_name, table_name|
  conn = connect(db_name)
  query_result = conn.exec_params("SELECT * FROM $1;", [table_name])
end
```

results in  `#<PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" LINE 1: SELECT * FROM $1; ^ >`

This seems like such a simple example to get working - am I fundamentally misunderstanding how to use this method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use placeholders for *values*, not for *identifiers* (such as table and column names). This is the one place where you're stuck using string interpolation to build your SQL. Of course, if you're using string wrangling for your SQL, you **must** be sure to properly quote/escape things; for identifiers, that means using [`quote_ident`](http://rubydoc.info/github/ged/ruby-pg/PGconn.quote_ident):

> `+ (Object) quote_ident(str)`
>
> Returns a string that is safe for inclusion in a SQL query as an identifier. Note: this is not a quote function for values, but for identifiers.

So you'd say something like:

```
table_name   = conn.quote_ident(table_name)
query_result = conn.exec("SELECT * FROM #{table_name}")
```

Comment: Ah ha, I wasn't aware of the distinction. Many thanks.

Comment: It is a common problem, makes sense if you think of identifiers like pieces of code and values like variables though.

Comment: @DavidJohnSmith Do you know what [`PG::TextEncoder::Identifier`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/TextEncoder/Identifier) is about, then?

Comment: @Alexander From the docs you linked to: "This encoder can also be used per `PG::Connection#quote_ident`". Looks like that's the class behind `conn.quote_ident`.

Comment: @muistooshort Yeah, I saw that, but I found it odd that such a simple function would delegate to an entire class. I kind of expected that there was some way I could use this class to automatically encode strings as identifiers to bind to SQL params.

Comment: @Alexander Might have to go on an adventure through the source (as is so often the case) to see if that encoder is used anywhere else.